# How to insert an image of a package into a PDF using iText?

Tags: java, netbeans, itext

I'm using the code below to insert an image in a PDF.

After generating the .jar file and trying to run it on another computer, the PDF is not generated.

When I remove the image from the project the PDF is generated normally.

Can you help me?

```
Image image1 = Image.getInstance("src\\assistentevirtual\\imagens\\trlogo.png");
image1.scaleAbsolute(120, 120);
image1.setAbsolutePosition(10, 720);
document.add(image1);
```

Comment: Expand the generated jar and check the structure to see if/where the png file was placed within the jar.  Then search on _getResourceAsStream_.  You should also log exceptions to get some context of the problem. Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you tell us how you generate your jar? Do you use maven? It seems that you load the image from the src folder which is later not integrated into the jar itself...

Comment: @Lonzak I use netbeans and press "Shift + F11".

Comment: @AndrewS How to expand .jar after generated?

Comment: A jar file is in compressed format (zip), so use your favorite tool to expand the file.

Comment: What happens when you press Shift+F11? I don't use netbeans. But besides that I think you need to familiarize yourself more with the topic.
Update: I just looked it up: `Shift-F11. Clean & build main project.` Do you see a pom.xml file somewhere?